# Bumblin' Stumblin' Rumblin' Jumblin'!

Tags: logical-deduction, word, wordplay, no-computers, anagram

<sub>This is an entry into the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/fortnightly-topic-challenge-36-twisted-classics-1)</sub>

Jumble<sub>®</sub> was one of my favorite puzzles growing up. They were quick and fun and relatively easy; they took just long enough to keep me occupied while eating cereal before the school bus came every morning.

Below are eight jumble-style puzzles, each with a picture that may help you to understand each section's respective answer.

The basic rules are these:

- Each puzzle consists of a series of anagrams for you to solve. Please note and respect the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag.
- The underscores(_) and boxes(⌼) show letter position. The ⌼ is an indicator that the specified letter(s) will be used in the solution of that individual Jumble-style puzzle. This solution will be a caption of sorts for the adjacent picture.
- The eight solutions will be comprised of (2) or (3) words, for a grand total of (18) words.
- The (18) solution words will fit (somehow) into the **Final Problem** as indicated by the "____" placeholders.
- The final word in the last couplet (indicated with "????") in the **Final Problem** is the ultimate goal.

Good luck and have fun!

---

[image: ![![enter image description here]

---

**The Final Problem:**

---

### `There was a ___ ___ who ___ like a ___.`

### `One day he ___ his ___ ; his ___ just went ___.`

### `His ___ ___ the dosage with ___ he had been ___.`

### `They ___ him up! They ___ him ___  of ___ ___ ___ ????™`

---

Comment: Jumble!! Ah, the memories!

Comment: Is it possible that in the first set, the letters you want from the fourth word are 1,4 rather than 1,5?

Comment: ... ah, no, looking at the final problem, perhaps not.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan always looking downfield, huh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks @Hagfy for these $^1$ (A really big part of the puzzle) 
Thanks @David Starkey for these $^2$

**Row 1**

> feared -> f d  $^1$ 
>  Violin -> i l i n 
>  Magic -> g i c 
>  Warthog -> w h 
>  devilish -> d h $^1$

Caption

> (WHICH FIDDLING) $^1$

---

**Row 2**

> firearm -> f i
>  regulator -> u o
>  Rifled -> f l d $^1$
>  Restricted -> s t e
>  Phalanx -> h l x $^1$

Caption

> Fixed Shot Full

---

**Row 3**

> Pocket -> o 
>  protector -> t 
>  goofball -> o o 
>  Magician -> m 
>  juggles -> j l s

Caption

> Lost mojo

---

**Row 4**

> Station -> s t i $^1$
>  methane -> h e
>  pollution -> p u $^1$
>  petrol -> e t r
>  chemistry -> h
>  gasoline -> g s

Caption

> Super High Test $^1$

---

**Row 5**

> Arboreal -> e l 
>  Haired -> h d $^1$
>  dirty -> dir
>  infested -> i d
>  accomplice -> c m p $^1$

Caption

> Riddled chimp

---

**Row 6**

> Prescribe -> e c $^1$ 
>  traction -> r c t o $^1$ 
>  Hospitalized -> h d $^1$ 
>  checkup? -> c k
>  scoped -> s o e d $^1$

Caption:

> Doctors checked

---

**Row 7**

> islander -> i a n r
>  zigzag -> z z
> creole -> el $^1$
>  republic -> pui  $^2$
> Habitat -> h a t $^1$

Caption:

> Haitian puzzler

---

**Row 8**

> flaccid -> l c i $^1$
>  Satisfy -> i $^2$
>  complete -> l e
>  harrumph -> m p $^1$ 
>  phony -> p n

Caption:

> Pencil Limp? $^1$

---

Final words:

> which fiddling 
>  Fixed shot full
>  lost mojo 
>  Super high test
>  Riddled chimp
>  Doctors checked
>  Haitian puzzler
>  Pencil limp

The Final Problem: $^1$, $^1$, $^1$, $^1$

> There was a HAITIAN PUZZLER who RIDDLED like a CHIMP.
> One day he LOST his MOJO; his PENCIL just went LIMP.
> His DOCTORS CHECKED the dosage with which he had been FIDDLING.
> They FIXED him up! They SHOT him FULL of SUPER HIGH TEST RIDDLING!™

Comment: I think I have a few more: rot13(1-SrnerQ,QrivyvfU; 2-evSYrQ,cUnYnaK; 4-FgnGVba,CbyyHgvba; 6-gEnPGvBa,FpBcRQ; 7-peRbYr?,UNovGng; 8-sYnPpVq,uneehZCu,CRAPVY YVZC?)

Comment: 7- erchoyvp, 8- fngvfsl

Comment: I think the last word of 1 is the first and last letter (D and H) which could give rot13(JUVPU SVQQYVAT)?  Also I have a misspelled possibility for 7: rot13(UNGVNA CHMMYRE)?

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake.

Comment: OH!  I think for 6 rot13(UbfcvgnyvmrQ -> QBPGBEF PURPXRQ).  Here's my final story so far: rot13(Gurer jnf n UNGVNA CHMMYRE jub ___ yvxr n ___.  Bar qnl ur YBFG uvf ZBWB; uvf CRAPVY whfg jrag YVZC.  Uvf QBPGBEF PURPXRQ gur qbfntr jvgu JUVPU ur unq orra SVQQYVAT.)  Nothing on the last line yet.

Comment: Uploaded fix for "misspelled possibility for 7: rot13(UNGVNA CHMMYRE)." Good eye, @hagfy!

Comment: I had UNVGNA instead of UNGVNA, but it should be right now.

Comment: Looks good to me!  Working backwards on the first word for 6 got me rot13(ceRfPevor).  Still pretty stumped on 5...maybe rot13(UnverQ,npPbZCyvpr)?

Comment: Added some to 5. 4 has all letters (I think)

Comment: I think rot13(ertHyngBe) for 2...just leaves one clue on 2 and the final answers for 2 and 4.  Unless anything is incorrect, that is.  I'm stuck trying to find a word for the fourth line that rhymes with the third.

Comment: The last clue for 2 could be rot13(SVernez), which would make the phrase ro13(SVKRQ FUBG SHYY).  That would fit the first half of the last line in the final phrase.

Comment: @PL457 Aha...I think rot13(Gurl SVKRQ uvz hc! Gurl FUBG uvz SHYY bs FHCRE UVTU GRFG **EVQQYVAT**)!

Comment: PL457  @hagfy: Nicely done to both of you. Inspiring to see such teamwork! Check coming...

Comment: @Chowzen Do you see an option to send a bounty or something to Hagfy? He really helped out with this one.

And I really likes this puzzle, would love it to see one again sometimes. :)

Comment: @PL457 Absolutely no need, but thank you. I just like the puzzles and trying to be helpful. Hoping you found it helpful and didn't feel like I was butting in. Chowzen, I agree, this puzzle was a lot of fun. Thanks!!  Sorry, accidentally posted this as an answer...